# How to fix "Access Denied to the action list and role LIST" message?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am using the Sonata Admin Bundle to manage some entities. One of my entities is called Equivalent. It has two simple fields.

I ran `sonata:admin:generate` to create an admin class for this new entity. The I/O is as follows:

```
The fully qualified model class: AppBundle\Entity\Equivalent
The bundle name [AppBundle]:
The admin class basename [EquivalentAdmin]:
Do you want to generate a controller [no]? yes
The controller class basename [EquivalentAdminController]:
Do you want to update the services YAML configuration file [yes]?
The services YAML configuration file [admin.yml]:
The admin service ID [app.admin.equivalent]:

The admin class "AppBundle\Admin\EquivalentAdmin" has been generated under the file "/usr/src/app/src/AppBundle/Admin/EquivalentAdmin.php".

The controller class "AppBundle\Controller\EquivalentAdminController" has been generated under the file "/usr/src/app/src/AppBundle/Controller/EquivalentAdminController.php".

The service "app.admin.equivalent" has been appended to the file "/usr/src/app/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml".
```

... and the problem is that now when I go to `/admin/app/equivalent/list` -- even as a superuser -- I get this error:

`Access Denied to the action list and role LIST`

So my question is: **How can I avoid this error and allow my superuser to access a listing?**

(Consider it to be a karmic bonus if you also include ways to allow other actions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops! A look at the database confirmed that my super user was actually not a super user. The user's "roles" field was mighty sparse, actually.

Taking a look at `security.yml` (and the `users` table in the database) and then fixing that lack of roles by using `fos:user:promote` "fixed" the problem temporarily.

======

Edit #1:

But trying those same steps a few days later did not solve the problem, so the question is still open.

======

Edit #2:

After some help from a coworker and a skim through https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/security.html, it became clear that the application is using some "magic" naming conventions to allow new `ROLE_` definitions in the `security.yml` file.

So because I had `app.admin.equivalent` defined as a service in my `admin.yml` file, I added `ROLE_APP_ADMIN_EQUIVALENT_LIST` in the relevant place in my `security.yml` file, and the list view started to work just fine for my user.